# R ggmap geocode administrative_area_level returns '1'

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap, geocode

I am trying to use ggmap to get the fields in administrative_area_level_3 from the google maps api. The single call returns the correct data. The below code returns a '1' for every entry from administrative_area_level_3.

```
# Geocoding a csv column of "addresses" in R

#load ggmap
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each  address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "more", source = "google")
origAddress$lon[i] <- as.character(result[1])
origAddress$lat[i] <- as.character(result[2])
origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[5])
origAddress$district[i] <- as.character(result[13])

}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

I modified these lines to get those fields:

```
origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[5])
origAddress$district[i] <- as.character(result[13])
```

When I run this I get the correct administrative_area_level_3

```
adr <- geocode("35880 WIDENER VALLEY RD Glade Spring VA", output = "more", source = "google")
```

Here is my CSV:

```
ID,addresses 
1,35880 WIDENER VALLEY RD Glade Spring VA
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly

Comment: Sorry, why is the script returning a '1' for field [13] and adr <- geocode("35880 WIDENER VALLEY RD Glade Spring VA", output = "more", source = "google") gives the correct  administrative_area_level_3  output?